Whenever I scroll my page, extra content of the parallax div starts to appear. How to fix it?
Here is the image of the extra part :

I tried overflow-y;hidden still it appears whenever i try to scroll it.
Here is the CSS code for the background and foreground images
#background{
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(-40px) scale(5);
}

#foreground{
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover ;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 60%;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(3);
}

HTML
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <h4 id="heading">developedbyed</h4>
        <button>SignUp</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="bg1.png" id="background" >
        <img src="girl1.png" id="foreground">
        <!-- <img src="rock1.png" id="vvv"> -->
        <h1>EXPLORE</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="image1">
                <img src="switzleft.png" class="xyz">
                <h3>Switzerland</h3>
                <h4>Mountains Of Tumbad</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="image2">
                <img src="switzright.png" class="xyz">
                <h3>Nepal</h3>
                <h4>Mountains Of Everest</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos magni at hic amet, officia rerum non vitae praesentium voluptates exercitationem? Molestias molestiae repudiandae repellat eum, vitae similique ipsum illo, voluptatum nostrum soluta autem ut consequuntur voluptates nemo id necessitatibus eligendi?
        </p>
        <p class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos magni at hic amet, officia rerum non vitae praesentium voluptates exercitationem? Molestias molestiae repudiandae repellat eum, vitae similique ipsum illo, voluptatum nostrum soluta autem ut consequuntur voluptates nemo id necessitatibus eligendi?
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

Apart from that i tried to fix the background, but that part still appears.
How can i fix it?

Your background and foreground images have different heights.
#foreground has a height of 100% of its container element, which could cause the edge of the parallax div to appear if its container element is not 100vh.
Would you mind including the HTML for these elements as well?

yeah nothing specific happened. The problem is when i scroll down parallax div portion appears... below the another div. I tried changing the height of background and foreground but still it is happening

I've run into problems similar if one of the parent elements (<body> or even the <html>) have differing heights. Since overflow-y: hidden didn't work, it may be an issue with another element. Difficult to tell without the full HTML and CSS for the elements.
